What is the name of this location in the Gerudo Highlands, at the top of a mountain?

Can anyone please help me name this location in The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild so I can look it up on the web? It is in the Gerudo Highlands, at the top of a mountain.

Can you add coordinates and/or a screenshot of the map? If possible can you activate the region's tower first, so the map is fully visible?

Asking for location names based on a photo is an ineffective way to find what you're looking for. There is a coordinate system in the game, and "botw lightning mural" (or similar search queries) already gets the job done. This is IMO an extension of the identification question premise, albeit asking to identify a location within a given game as opposed to a game in and of itself.

This is the location of where Keeha Yoog Shrine is.  It is featured in the Cliffside Etchings shrine quest.
